# Weird upload speed in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, upload

I have a SG VPS with roughly 1Gbps upload & download, and this is confirmed through [`speedtest-cli`](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli) to multiple server, and my ISP's max download speed is 20Mbps

However me and other users facing a very slow download speed (when downloading a file from the server). After some investigation, I found a weird upload speed behavior on my server.

The scenario is:

1. Start downloading one file, the speed is 2MBps+ (My ISP's max download speed)
2. Cancelled the download, and redownload again, now the speed goes down to 500-700KBps
3. Added one more download (now downloading 2 files at the same time), 2nd download speed is 500-700KBps too, and doesn't seem to affect the 1st download speed (now only around 1.5MBps in total)
4. Added one more download (now downloading 3 files at the same time), the 3rd download speed is 1.5MBps and seems to affect the first and second download speed a bit (now 2MBps+ in total which is the expected max speed)

Take a look at the demonstration video here: https://youtu.be/PIX8JitRX98

Regarding the 1st and 2nd scenario, every time I started a new download from my server to my local address, I got small chance (about one in ten) to have a full speed (2MBps+) and it will never go down to 500-700KBps, but if I restart the download, the speed immediately goes down to 500-700KBps again. Take a look of the video I uploaded here: https://youtu.be/qsTaeLUIWWQ . Looks like the speed is changing every time I start a new download

What I have tried:

- Using VPN (private internet access) with many different region
- Tried 3 different ISP
- Asked my other friends who lives in the same country as me with different ISP

and all of them are facing the same issue

MTR / Tracert from local PC to the server and vice versa shows good latency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved by itself. Seems like a problem from the route between the ISPs and the server rather than the server it self.